# Vim update file name

Tags: vim

My .vimrc is configured as follows:

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline +=%1*\ %F  
set statusline +=%1*%=%5l%* 
set statusline +=%2*/%L%*
set statusline +=%1*%4v\ %*
set statusline +=%2*0x%04B\ %*
```

Whenever I save the file with a different name inside vim, I want the name of the file to reflect the new name rather than displaying the old one. What do I need to alter in-order to get this behavior ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%F` should get you the (full) current filename. I suspect you do the saving with `:w newname`. That just writes the buffer *once* to that new name, but keeps the original one. To rename the current buffer, use `:saveas newname` instead.

There's also the `:file newname` command to rename without writing (right now). And you can query the current name via `:echo expand('%')`.

Comment: I use the split window editing method in vim. When I used the `:file newname` option, both the windows get updated to the new file. What I was looking for is that in one window I want the original file open and the other window I want the alter the old file and save it in a different name.

Comment: After using `:file` or `:saveas`, just use `:edit #` (or `:split #`) to get back to the original file.